# svg works in chrome but disappear in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, svg

The svg rect works well in chrome, but not in firefox. What is the problem? Also, is there any special rules in using svg in firefox?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>

<head>
<style>
rect {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    fill: green
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<svg width="400px" height="110px">
  <rect/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works if you set width and height as attributes instead of CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/c9fc1k9y/

Comment: I find out firefox doesn't support setting width in <style> tag. Thanks!